# spark-shell command error: No such file or directory

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I installed spark and java but when I run spark-shell I get this error:
/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /home/usseer/Documents/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: please check JAVA_HOME in spark-env.sh

Comment: @dassum it is : JAVA_HOME=/home/usseer/Documents/jdk1.8.0_201